# how to make each individual flow object have its own Offset number?

Tags: physics

[image]Trying to make flow object with Physics Fluid simulation: (type: flow, flow type: liquid, flow behavior: Geometry) to emit fluid at a certain later keyframe, and not at frame 1.

I was able to time what frame is the start of the emission with Offset under cache, but I'm not sure how to individually make each emission object start at different frames?

I have 5 flow objects in one domain.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use inflow object, and keyframe only one frame as active like so:

[image]

so "use flow" should be off on "frame - 1", on for your frame, off for "frame +1"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice idea!.....

Comment: Thank you ‼️‼️